# What is the difference between for each and traditional for loop in Java in terms of shadowing?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

This is the code I have:

```
class HelloWorld {

    char[] foo = {'a', 'b'};

    // This will compile
    void foo() {
        for (char foo : foo) {
        }
    }

    // This will not compile
    void bar() {
        for (char foo = 0; foo < foo.length; foo++) {
        }
    }
}
```

How come `foo` compiles but compiling `bar` fails with:

```
Error: char cannot be dereferenced
```

What is the difference between the two loop declarations that makes loop in foo compile but bar fail?

Comment: you are are logically operating/ Comparing [ < ]between Characters and integers  -> how can that be non eorneuos

Comment: Are you using a ++ in a char type? And if you use the same name foo for the ireration variable than the array variable that must be the error

Comment: Why does `bar` use a `char` variable? Shouldn't it be an `int`? Does it still exhibit the same behavior if you use an `int`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can see the difference by looking at [JLS§14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)'s description of how the enhanced `for` works when handling an array:

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:
>
> ```
> T[] #a = Expression;
> L1: L2: ... Lm:
> for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
>     {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
>     Statement
> }
> ```

Note how the variable is declared within the *body* of the loop, not the header of the loop. That is, your `foo` function is like this:

```
void foo() {
    { // Freestanding block for scope, though not really needed as `foo` has
      // nothing else in it
        char[] a = foo;       // T[] #a = Expression;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            char foo = a[i];  // {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
        }
    }
}
```

That's why you get away with the shadowing in the enhanced `for`, and not in the traditional `for`, which needs to access the original array (to get its `length`, to get the entry for `i`, etc.).

More about the enhanced `for` loop in [*How does the Java 'for each' loop work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) and its answers.

Answer (score 8):

The Java Language Specification defines the scopes of your two `char foo`'s differently:

> The scope of a local variable declared in the *ForInit* part of a basic
>   `for` statement (§14.14.1) includes all of the following:
>
> - Its own initializer
> - Any further declarators to the right in the *ForInit* part of the `for` statement
> - The *Expression* and *ForUpdate* parts of the `for` statement
> - The contained Statement
>
> The scope of a local variable declared in the *FormalParameter* part of
>   an enhanced `for` statement (§14.14.2) is the contained Statement.

([JLS 8, section 6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3))

That perfectly explains your observed behavior: the local `foo` is in scope in the control clause of the basic `for` loop (everywhere to the right of its declaration) and therefore it shadows the other `foo` there, but in the enhanced `for` loop its scope is only the loop statement -- it is not in scope anywhere in the loop control clause.